# Inherit generic class T must be a reference type

Tags: c#, generics

```
public class _Base_Client<T> : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<T>
```

It complains that `The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TChannel'`

T is a reference to an interface.

Here is the line I wish to change to use the new base class

```
public class EchoServiceClient : 
    System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<IEchoService>, IEchoService
```

How can I fix this? thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change:

```
public class _Base_Client<T> : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<T>
```

To:

```
public class _Base_Client<T> : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<T> where T : class
```

The constraints in your class must be at least as strict as the constraints defined in its base class (`ClientBase`).  To wit, here is the declaration of `ClientBase`:

```
public abstract class ClientBase<TChannel> : ICommunicationObject, 
    IDisposable where TChannel : class
```

Notice the `class` constraint.

Comment: perfect, thanks. I now see the :class restraint in the object viewer. thanks for pointing that out too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the interface in there. You need a concrete implementation of `IEchoService`.